# what is javascript `function *`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

from http://koajs.com/

```
app.use(function *() {
    this.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

My question is : What is `function *` it relative to [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)  ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function*

Comment: yes, `function *` is `function*`, may have a bit confusing